# How is OLR power of the atmosphere distributed with altitude?

Tags: climate-change, climate-models

The OLR (outgoing longwave radiation) from the top of the atmosphere to space is composed of radiative energy emitted by the atmosphere at all altitudes, as well as the surface.

1. How is the radiative power of the OLR leaving the top of the atmosphere distributed with the altitude the OLR originated from?
2. How is that distribution changing over time?